# Is there a service in US that allows to make payment on my behalf

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, international-transfer, online-tools

I got [parking ticket in Washington and having hard time paying it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55403/how-do-i-pay-for-a-us-parking-ticket-from-the-uk), I have left the States since.

**Is there a online service in US that allows to make payment on my behalf, that I could use to pay this fine?**

Comment: I believe if you don't pay it  yourself - it will be billed to the rental company. They will charge a hefty fee, but they will pay it for you.

Comment: @littleadv Hi, chances are they will. I still find it hard to believe that there is no way (without asking someone from States) to be able to pay a fine from abroad.

Comment: The US is not very advanced when it comes to consumer financial services.

Comment: Looking at that other question, why can't you just get a money order from your bank and mail it to the address?  seems like a simple solution.

Comment: @NotMe: It's not necessarily so easy to get a money order in US dollars from a UK bank. In particular, I am guessing that the money order would need a US routing number so that the payee can process it like an ordinary US check.

Comment: @NateEldredge: All they are going to do is deposit it.  The banks should be able to figure out how to get the money transferred.

Comment: @NotMe: I wouldn't be confident of that.  If you walk into a US bank with a check drawn on a foreign bank, they typically won't accept it for deposit.  They *might* agree to send it for collection - where they mail it back to the drawee bank and ask them to wire or otherwise transfer the funds, which only then are credited to your account - but they will charge you a fee for this.    I am going to go out on a limb and say that the DC DMV is not going to want to do this - when their bank refuses it as a deposit, they will bounce it back to you, probably with a penalty.

Comment: In my business I've deposited many foreign checks.  Yes, there is usually a waiting period before the funds are available.  In a few cases I've seen it take up to 30 days.

Comment: @NotMe: Well, post an answer if you like.  I personally wouldn't be comfortable with recommending what you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you live near a US military base, then it will probably have a US Post Office.  From there you can buy a money order (in US dollars), which is one of the forms of payment that the District of Columbia will accept by mail.

There's also something that goes by the name "demand draft" that you might be able to get at your UK bank but will actual draw from an account on a US bank.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_draft

Comment: If the post office is actually on the base, a non-American civilian probably wouldn't be allowed to enter the base, and couldn't go there.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's certainly a possibility that would have to be evaluated in context.  Depends on the security rules and where the post office sits on the grounds. It's worth checking if he's nearby and otherwise stuck for options to make the payment.